# What exactly is the Excel XML 2003-2004 format?

Tags: xml, excel

The open-source [xls.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls) library is built for the BIFF-based XLS format, and the XML-based [Excel 2003-2004 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats). Note that this is not the [Open XML formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) seen in Excel 2007-2013. So what exactly are these? Does it mean that all/some `.xls` Excel 2003 files are XML-based? Or does this apply to some other type of Excel document? (templates, macros, scripts)

The wikipedia entry further states that there is loss of fidelity when using such XML formats for spreadsheet storage, which was corrected in the 2007 formats, so is there a prompt asking the user to confirm if he would like to use XML or binary? Or are all documents created in Excel 2003 automatically XML? And for such XML documents is the extension `.xml`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Office 2003 was the first version supporting some kind of rudimentary XML format, now superseded with the new Office 2007+ format.

Excel 2003 would open/save spreadsheets in XML format. Those files are still using the XLS extension.

Refer to this [blog](https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/how-to-read-and-write-office-2003-excel-xml-files/) for some more details